# Instantiate and initialise a struct dynamically

Tags: c++, struct

I am initialising a c style struct using a list:

```
FooBar fb = { 12, 3.4 };
```

this works fine, but how would i create the struct dynamically using this curvy brace notation?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++11,

```
std::unique_ptr<FooBar> fb {new FooBar {12, 3.4}};
```

In C++03, you can't.

Answer (score 3):

C++11:

```
FooBar* fb = new FooBar{ 12, 3.4 };
```

You can also use it in containers:

```
std::vector<FooBar> v;
v.push_back({ 12, 3.4 });
```